# Mongo $and query returning no results

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I approach writing a query to return all the records matching both match.id and player.name for the following collection?

```
{
    "match": {
        "id": 1,
        "event": {
            "timestamp": "2015-06-03 15:02:22",
            "event": "round_stats",
            "round": 1,
            "player": {
                "name": "Jim",
                "userId": 45,
                "uniqueId": "BOT",
                "team": 2
            },
            "shots": 0,
            "hits": 0,
            "kills": 0,
            "headshots": 0,
            "tks": 0,
            "damage": 0,
            "assists": 0,
            "assists_tk": 0,
            "deaths": 0,
            "head": 0,
            "chest": 0,
            "stomach": 0,
            "leftArm": 0,
            "rightArm": 0,
            "leftLeg": 0,
            "rightLeg": 0,
            "generic": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I've attempted it with both the following query statements, but had no luck -- they both return no results:

```
db.warmod_events.find( { $and: [ { "match.id": 1}, { "player.name": 'Jim' } ] } )

db.warmod_events.find( { $and: [ { "match.id": 1}, { "event": { "player.name": "Jim" } } ] } )
```

I'm pretty new to Mongo and any guidance and explanation would help a bunch -- truthfully I've chosen to use Mongo for this project as the data I am working with is already presented in this form (the JSON) and, due to that, it seemed like a good opportunity to use and learn Mongo.

I am referring to the documentation on the Mongo site currently.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
db.warmod_events.find({ "match.id": 1, "match.event.player.name": 'Jim' })
```

which will match documents where the match id is the same as the embedded document player name.